# Using .scroll() to control transform property

Tags: jquery, css, transform, css-transitions

I'm a jQuery beginner, so I'm just looking for some hints so that I can keep trudging in the right direction.

What I want to have happen is: a fixed image rotates while the user is scrolling down the page. Ideally at a matched rate of rotation with the scrolling (fast scroll = fast rotate).

This is where I'm at:

```
$(window).scroll(function () { 
  $("img").css("-webkit-transform","rotate(90deg)") 
});
```

I know I need to use a smaller increment than 90deg, and of course will need more vendor prefixes, but my main problem here is that this only gets the image to rotate 90deg one time. At the very least I want it to be clunkily rotating over and over. Then I can work on trying to get it smooth.

Thanks

Comment: I know this isn't what you're asking, but if you want a nice cross-browser plug-in for rotating, you can try http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking for is basically how a any parallax site would work - certain elements are tied to the action of scrolling. To make that work, you get the position of the window for every time the scroll occurs.

This will be hard to wrap your head around at first but using that scroll position, you make a calculation that then goes into the degress of rotation.

Read through this tutorial to get a better idea of what I mean about scroll position.

[Parallax Tutorial](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/07/12/behind-the-scenes-of-nike-better-world/)

Comment: Thanks. What I was looking for is very simple, and I did figure it out with this:

x=0
$(document).ready(function(){
$(window).scroll(function () { 
$("#gear").css("-vendor-transform","rotate(" + (x+=3) + "deg)");
 });
});

But I just heard about this whole parallax thing, so thanks for the tut!